# Find height of the triangle (antenna) given angle of elevation and displacement from base

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

> A man standing near a radio station antenna observes that the angle of elevation to the top of the antenna is $A = 63°$. He then walks $s = 130$ feet further away and observes that the angle of elevation to the top of the antenna is $B = 49°$ (see the figure below). Find the height of the antenna to the nearest foot. (Hint: Find $x$ first.)
>
> [image]

I get $362\ \mathrm{ft}$, but apparently that's incorrect.

Comment: do you know what the answer should be?

Comment: Because I get what Carlster get's which is $\approx 361.3507184$ which is very close to yours (besides maybe a rounding error) so I thought I may have been wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{height}}{\text{distance}}=\tan(63°)\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\text{height}}{\text{distance}+130}=\tan(49°)$$

therefore

$$\begin{align}
&&\tan(63°)\times d&=d\times\tan(49°)+130\times\tan(49°)\\
\implies &&d&=\frac{130\times\tan(49°)}{(\tan(63°)-\tan(49°))}\\
\implies &&\text{height}&=\frac{\tan(63°)\times130\times\tan(49°)}{(\tan(63°)-\tan(49°))}
\end{align}$$

And that, my friend, is what you have ($\approx361.35$).

Answer (score 0):

From figure directly

$$h (\cot B - \cot A)= 130 $$

$$ \dfrac{130}{(\cot 49^0 - \cot 63^0)} = h = 361.351^{\prime} $$

a common problem in heights/distances in Trigonometry.